# dismissing modal view controller causes music to stop

Tags: iphone, ios5, audio, modalviewcontroller

I'm creating an application where I need to have the background music playing all the time. At the application launch, I start playing the music and everything's fine until I dismiss the modal view controller (I do this to go back to the main screen of the app). At this point, the music suddenly stops and when I try to adjust the volume it actually says "ringer".... after 5-10 sec it goes back to "volume"  and I can launch the music again.

Has anyone come across this issue? I'm having a really hard time pinpointing the source of the problem...

edit:
This is how I start playing music (theData is my shared data object)

```
NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bg" ofType:@"mp3"]; 

theData.backgroundMusicPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath] error:nil];

theData.backgroundMusicPlayer.delegate = self;

[theData.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];

[theData.backgroundMusicPlayer play];

theData.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

In the app, I have two scenes: I perform a segue to go from scene 1 to scene 2 and then to go back I use the following code:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 [theScene removeSubviews];
```

The method removeSubviews:

```
[fbInfoView removeFromSuperview];
[logoView removeFromSuperview];
 self.captureSession=nil;  // ending AVCaptureSession
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you painted a better picture of the structure of your application.  Code would be good, too.

Comment: Can you post the code where you start playing the music?

Comment: I edited the initial post to provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear how you create and setup `theData`, but I suggest you use a singleton object for this purpose. Something like this:

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject {

}
+(MySingleton*)sharedHelper;
-(void)playMusic;
@end
```

The implementation:

```
@implementation MySingleton
static MySingleton* _sharedMySingleton = nil;

+(MySingleton*)sharedHelper
{
    if (!_sharedMySingleton)
        [[self alloc] init];

    return _sharedMySingleton;

    return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
    NSAssert(_sharedMySingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
    _sharedMySingleton = [super alloc];
        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialize stuff here
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)playMusic
{
   // your code
}

    @end
```

And call it like this:

```
[[MySingleton sharedHelper] playMusic];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm quite sure that the problem is not related to theData. Actually, if I don't even initalise and launch the music, the volume goes to ringer after dismissing the modal VC...